# How to manage K8s objects with Ansible from src URL not local file?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform to deploy a Kubernetes Cluster and Ansible for deploying K8s objects. Everything works, using [Ansible K8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html), also deploying from local YAML files, but when I try to use lookup from url like described [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48402#issuecomment-546414684) I get an error:

> ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state

Part of the Ansible Tasks:

```
- name: Fip-Controller rbac
  k8s:
    api_key: "{{ api_token }}"
    host: "{{ api_url }}"
    state: present
    definition: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{lookup('url', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cbeneke/hcloud-fip-controller/master/deploy/rbac.yaml', split_lines=False) | from_yaml_all | list}}"
  when: item is not none
```

I also tried the exact same like described [here (same link as above)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48402#issuecomment-546414684).

[A related Github issue with the same error](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32554)

I would be grateful if anybody could point me in any direction. Is there a better solution for adding YAMLs from urls?

Ansible: v2.9.1
OS: macOS Mojave

Comment: Tested same url with success. Mine ansible version is 2.9.2. Removed api_key & host lines cause have already kubeconfig file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known problem with using some Python packages under OSX. Exporting this variable solved my problem:

`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`

[See this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32499)